# .htaccess internal redirect not working for subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that has another site inside of it in a sub folder. For example, `www.domain.com` and the sub folder would be `www.domain.com/uk/`. They both contain duplicate files, so even the `.htaccess` file is same. Now the problem is when I redirect users through `.htaccess` inside the `uk` subfolder to a file in the same directory it redirects them to the file in the parent site with the duplicate name.

This is the rule I have used in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^category/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ final_final.php
```

I don't have much experience with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the parent directory `RewriteBase` should be `/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

in the subdirectory the `RewriteBase` should be `/uk`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /uk
```

Comment: i've already tried to set the rewrite base to /uk but it doesn't work

Comment: still redirects to the parent directory file

Comment: fixed how? its not an actual page

Comment: can you post exactly your `.htaccess` files? just the related scripts.

Comment: but if i redirect a user to this path www.domain.com/uk/category/watever follos this , then the server should redirect them to www.domain.com/uk/filename.php

Comment: it works on the parent site but not on the /uk site which resides inside parent in a folder

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On



  

RewriteRule ^category/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ final_final.php  

RewriteRule ^category/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ final_final.php  






RewriteBase /

</IfModule>

Comment: put `RewriteBase /uk/` before `RewriteRule`

Comment: now the ^products redirect to final3.php is not working , what to do ?

Comment: i don't know what final3 is. can you post you script?

Comment: RewriteRule ^products/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ final3.php 

RewriteRule ^products/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ final3.php

Comment: its from the same .htaccess file

Comment: always put the longest options condition that begin  with similar ones before the shorter condition line. because if you don't, the short one that placed earlier will be fired first.

Comment: is `final3.php` in the same uk directory?

Comment: No, i mean, put the longest one first. anyway it guess there is something else i can't figure out what. what kind of errors/behaviour u got?

Comment: it redirects me to a blank page with the the generated path on top

Comment: no clue. plz edit you question and submit both you full .htaccess files

Answer (score 0):

you can also specify concrete path in concrete redirect, it is not quite "clean" like Gustonez way but it may work too
in uk-htaccess redirect to uk base directory

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /uk/$1 [L,R]
```

and in parent-htaccess redirect to base directory without /uk/

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

but redirect you have is weird i think

```
^category/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ final_final.php
```

do you really need all this parameters in url to redirect?
and when you redirect any of these parameters will be parsed on page
you just going to final_final.php page without sending parameters to this page
another thing is that you don't have [L] flag a the end of statement
you better tell exactly what you need because this redirect you have may be inadequate and may not work at all

Comment: thanks for the advice i have modified my .htaccess as per ur suggestions and it works now .