# Alias and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get Symfony1.4 and Symfony2 working on the same host in Apache (2.2.22) - I think the problem is that both are using mod_rewrite to direct the request to a php controller/script. Here is my config

httpd.conf

```
# Symfony 1.4
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/wlnew/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "d:/wamp/www/wlnew/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf d:/wamp/www/wlnew/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "d:/wamp/www/wlnew/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# Symfony 2
Alias /another "d:/wamp/www/another/web/"
<Directory "d:/wamp/www/another/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And then each version of Symfony has a `.htaccess` which is used to re-write the request

Symfony 1 `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Symfony 2 `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to be able to use `localhost/` to redirect to Symfony 1 front controller `index.php` but when I use `localhost/another` all requests should be forwarded to the symfony2 front controller `app.php` but they aren't - they are forwarded to the symfony1 front controller (`index.php`). If I use the file name of the controller for Symfony2 it works ie `localhost/another/app.php`

How can I get apache to forward requests to the Symfony2 controller when i use the `/another` alias ?

### Update

I enabled logging of rewrite logging ... this is what I got :

```
[perdir D:/wamp/www/another/web/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/another/web/ -> 
[perdir D:/wamp/www/another/web/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
[perdir D:/wamp/www/another/web/] RewriteCond: input='D:/wamp/www/another/web/' pattern='!-f' => matched
[perdir D:/wamp/www/another/web/] rewrite '' -> 'app.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/another/web/] add per-dir prefix: app.php -> D:/wamp/www/another/web/app.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/another/web/] internal redirect with D:/wamp/www/another/web/app.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] add path info postfix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp -> D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp/www/another/web/app.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp/www/another/web/app.php -> wamp/www/another/web/app.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'wamp/www/another/web/app.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] add path info postfix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp -> D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp/www/another/web/app.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp/www/another/web/app.php -> wamp/www/another/web/app.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] applying pattern '^([^.]+)$' to uri 'wamp/www/another/web/app.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] add path info postfix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp -> D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp/www/another/web/app.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp/www/another/web/app.php -> wamp/www/another/web/app.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'wamp/www/another/web/app.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] RewriteCond: input='D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp' pattern='!-f' => matched
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] rewrite 'wamp/www/another/web/app.php' -> 'index.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] strip document_root prefix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/index.php -> /index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/index.php -> index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] applying pattern '^$' to uri 'index.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/index.php -> index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] applying pattern '^([^.]+)$' to uri 'index.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/index.php -> index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] RewriteCond: input='D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[perdir D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/] pass through D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/index.php
```

It seems that the `.htaccess` for the Symfony2 (`/another`) is being read and redirects to `app.php` but then reads the other `.htaccess` and then redirects to `index.php` ... How can i get the rewrite to stop at `app.php`

Comment: What if you move your alias for sf2 on top of your conf file?

Comment: @cheesemacfly no difference :-(

Comment: Same behavior for both `localhost/another` and `localhost/another/`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly yep - The problem seems to be with the Symfony 1 `.htaccess` - it cannot find a file so it redirects to `index.php` for some reason the alias seems to be ignored

Comment: At first look, I see that your `Alias /another "d:/wamp/www/another/web/"` has a trailing slash for the directory whereas your `<Directory "d:/wamp/www/another/web">` directive declaration does not. The one for 1.4 looks fine though. Maybe? :)

Comment: Though the trailing slash does not affect Directory directive. It is important only for other directives such as DocumentRoot and Location.

Comment: @NandeepMali I have tried all combinations of the slash - still no joy - i think the problem is the multiple `.htaccess` files - i have included the log

Comment: I figured. As I wrote in the second comment, it shouldn't matter. But you could try this: https://gist.github.com/9488026f5cefd8ccee3c (Added in gist because the reply is lengthy but uncertain as no machine to try it out).

Comment: Just updated the gist a bit.

Comment: @NandeepMali I think you might be on to something here - going to test now.

Comment: @NandeepMali adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/app.php` made no difference i changed it to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=D:/wamp/www/wlnew/web/wamp` samething ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23593/discussion-between-nandeep-mali-and-manseuk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the configuration requires `RewriteBase` needs to be set for both the .htaccess.

```
RewriteBase /another
```

This should work. [This link helped in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743060/htaccess-internal-redirect-not-working-for-subfolder)

Also, [here are some notes through our discussion on chat](https://gist.github.com/9488026f5cefd8ccee3c) on how other settings can affect and how `RewriteCond` can rectify infinite internal redirect loops. Might help other people. Overall, mod_rewrite is one difficult module.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the Symfony 2 alias inside the `VirtualHost` and add another `DirectoryIndex` for sf2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Symfony 1.4
  DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/wlnew/web"
  <Directory "d:/wamp/www/wlnew/web">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf d:/wamp/www/wlnew/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "d:/wamp/www/wlnew/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  # Symfony 2
  Alias /another "d:/wamp/www/another/web/"
  <Directory "d:/wamp/www/another/web">
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still the same problem .. thanks for the answer though .. seems that no one has Symfony1.4 and Symfony2 running together .. I have an application written in 1.4 that im migrating to 2 - everything else co-exists other then this !!!

Comment: Well this is strange, I've tested (with empty directory, not with an instance of each symfony) and the behavior was correct.

Comment: I will strip my httpd.conf right down and test - but when using the above the request for localhost/another is still answered by the symfony1.4 controller

Comment: Nope - still the same - index.php still answering requests when requesting `localhost/another` or `localhost/another/` - its as thought the `.htaccess` in `/another/web` is being ignored